# A sed result to be inserted into another file

Tags: string, sed

How can a sed result be inserted into another file directly at a specific point of patterned string ? as below just clarifying illustration:

```
sed -E 's/foo/foo\0bar/' foo | sed -E '/^bar$/i{ }' bar   # ?
```

so insert `{ }` inside the bar file at position of line being a `bar` string

Comment: `sed -i 's/foo/foo\0bar\n{ }/' file`? Why do you use `-E`? Why do you pipe `sed` output if the second `sed` reads from `bar`? And `'s/foo/foo\0bar/` is missing a `'`. Why do you insert a zero byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/bar/e sed -n "\\#foo#p" file1' file2
```

This will insert the line(s) matching `foo` in file1 before line(s) matching `bar` in file2.